# How to compare DBSCAN clustering results

Tags: clustering, dbscan

I want to decide which are the most relevant attributes for clustering algorithms.

My dataset has attribute this way:

```
 DBSCAN(data[latitude, Longitude, att1, att2, att3, att4, att5] ) 
 DBSCAN(data[att1, att2, att3, att4, att5] )
```

What metrics should I use in this case ?  Should I decide based on Homogeneity and Completeness ?

Answer (score 2):

DBSCAN does not operate on the raw attributes. It is distance based.

Therefore, **evaluate your distance measure**, and the relevancy of attributes for distance and similarity measurement. Then DBSCAN should be fine.

Directly comparing DBSCAN results with internal evaluation measures will likely *not* work. The internal evaluation measures seem to be designed for k-means and similar algorithms; and usually cannot deal reasonably with "noise" as produced by DBSCAN.

Given that you have attributes "latitude" and "longitude": **do not use Euclidean distance on these**. Earth is not flat, but (approximately) a spheroid. Treating latitude and longitude as  coordinates in Euclidean space is bogus. Use geodetic distance, and combine this with a similarity measure on your other attributes in a carefully chosen way. Or use GeneralizedDBSCAN!